# What does SpaceX do with all the engines?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, merlin-1d

SpaceX has had 8 successful launches in 2016 according to [a wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9#Launch_history). The [launch manifest](http://www.spacex.com/missions) agrees with that, but leaves out the launch pad failure.

According to another wikipedia article, they are producing around 200 engines per year:

> By June 2015, SpaceX was producing Merlin engines at the rate of four Merlin 1D engines per week, with a total production capacity in the factory of a maximum of five per week.

9 launches gives 90 engines (9+1 per flight), if I am not mistaken. That leaves 110 unused. There are also 45 recovered engines. In principle, SpaceX has a stockpile of Merlin engines for at least 11 launches, so what are they doing with all these Merlins?

Answer (score 4):

> ... are producing at the RATE of four Merlin 1D engines per week.

That is the key. They have had two stand downs due to loss of vehicles (CRS-7 in flight, AMOS-6 during a test). During that time, they can stop production, when it is clear they have a 3-6 months recovery ahead of themselves. Or else they can assume they will recover next week, continue at the 4/week build rate and only once it is clear their stores are full, pause production.

It is clear that SpaceX has decided that they need modifications to the basic Falcon 9 design for easier, better, faster, cheaper reuse after recovering a bunch of stages.  The initial engines recovered first were used for tests. One core is [on display with 9 engines at the Hawthorne factory](http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Falcon-9-700x432.jpg).

One of the cores was fired multiple times at the McGregor test site (JCSAT-14 mission).

One of the cores is being rebuilt into one of the Falcon Heavy demo flight's side boosters.  (Thaicomm-8 mission).

One is being reused as a launch vehicle for SES-10 satellite (CRS-8 mission).